# Two integers start and end

Tags: java

> Write a program that reads two integers start and end from the user
>   and prints the number from start to end inclusive. However, If end was
>   less than start than you should print them in descending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int start = scan.nextInt();
    int end = scan.nextInt();

    if(start < end)
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            System.out.print(i + " ");

    else if(start > end)
        for(int i = start; i >= end; i--)
            System.out.print(i + " ");  
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra brace at the end (possibly from your upper class declaration), did you mean to include that?

Comment: yh it's from the upper class declaration. The online judge gave me a 47/100, so I'm trying to figure out what's wrong or missing.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and add in your upper class declaration for completeness.

Comment: That's not exactly the problem now. I sent the complete code to the judge.

Answer (score 5):

#### Input checking

The most obvious issue that I see is that you are not verifying that the correct input is being entered. For example, if you enter a String instead of an int:

> ```
> > hello
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:8)
> ```

A natural way to do this is with [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29). Also, consider adding a little bit of feedback so it is less confusing for the user. Something like this, for example:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start;
    int end;

    System.out.println("Enter 1st whole number: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Input must be a whole number. Try again:");
        scan.next();
    }
    start = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd whole number: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Input must be a whole number. Try again:");
        scan.next();
    }
    end = scan.nextInt();
```

Result:

> ```
> Enter 1st whole number: 
> > hello
> Input must be a whole number. Try again:
> > 5
> Enter 2nd whole number: 
> > world
> Input must be a whole number. Try again:
> > 20
> 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> ```

One other (more general) method (though it is more of an anti-pattern in this particular case) to validate things is with a try/catch block. See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912917/3626537) for an example on how to do this.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start;
    int end;

    try { 
        System.out.println("Enter 1st number:");
        start = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number:");
        end = scan.nextInt();

    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Input must be an integer.");
        System.out.println("Exiting program.");
        return;
    }
```

> ```
> Enter 1st number:
> > hello
> Input must be an integer.
> Exiting program.
> ```

---

#### Formatting

One other remark, although it is more stylistic, it is often considered a good habit in general to include braces in Java even when they are not needed. So this bit:

> ```
> if(start < end)
>     for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
>         System.out.print(i + " ");
>
> else if(start > end)
>     for(int i = start; i >= end; i--)
>         System.out.print(i + " ");
> ```

Would look like this:

```
    if(start < end) {
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    else if(start > end) {
        for(int i = start; i >= end; i--) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");  
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that validating user input with try...catch is an anti-pattern, at least in a case as simple as this one. `Scanner` class exposes a `hasNextInt` method for this very purpose. I agree with bracing, I wouldn't skip braces.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know about that... let me edit that in, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the criteria this online judge uses, but these loops are repetitive.

```
if(start < end)
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        System.out.print(i + " ");

else if(start > end)
    for(int i = start; i >= end; i--)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
```

`else` is redundant here, by the way - `start` couldn't be at the same time smaller and greater than `end`.

It could be replaced by:

```
int step = start < end ? 1 : -1;
for (int i = start; i != end + step; i += step) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Also note that your original code ignored possibility that start == end (it wouldn't print anything in that case), whereas the task description doesn't rule it out.

Comment: start isn't smaller and greater than end at the same time. I've put an if statement. If start > end, enter the loop, or else enter the next loop.

Comment: @HovigArtinian and for this very reason your `else` is redundant. These two conditions are mutually exclusive already. It's not like removing `else` could cause both loops to execute. So basically it's a safeguard against the impossible (unless `start` or `end` were modified within the first `if` block, which isn't the case).

Comment: @KonradMorawski, Isn't your min/max introducing a bug? If the user inputs `start > end`, the step is correctly set to `-1`, but from is then set to `end`, so in effect you'll have a never ending loop...

Comment: @holroy hm, I think you're right. I overdid it :) I'll update the code. Good catch, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Three cases** are possible: `start < end`, `start > end`, and `start == end`.  You have only covered the first two.  I would expect that if `start == end`, then it prints one number.

It would be nice to have one generic solution that handles all three cases without **copy-and-pasted code**.

**Ending the output with a space** rather than a newline is untidy.  Even if the challenge doesn't specify exactly how the output should be terminated, I would put a newline there as a matter of convention.  In fact, since the challenge doesn't specify a delimiter, I'd just use `System.out.println(i)` for all of the numbers.

The way you **omitted the "optional" braces** is really nasty.  Don't do that!  When you omit braces like that, someday you *will* be blamed for introducing a bug, perhaps a [costly one](https://gotofail.com/).

My suggested solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int start = scan.nextInt();
        int end = scan.nextInt();

        for (int delta = (start < end) ? +1 : -1; ; start += delta) {
            System.out.println(start);
            if (start == end) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some issues in your code as I see it:

- *Repetitive `for`-loop* – You can use one `for`-loop, if you just switch the step of it
- *No input validation* – You don't verify that your input is integer, or loop if it fails
- *No new line at end of output* – This is a minor, but you don't end the output with a new line. And it could be argued that you possibly should try to insert newlines somewhere along the way
- *No documentation or comments* – It is always nice to have a little documentation, at least if the code isn't dead obivous
- *Missing braces around `if`- or `for`-blocks* – It is better to always include the braces, to keep you safe of indentation errors and unclear code

If we in addition add a little string.formatting, a static initialization of the scanner, and add a function for validating integer input, we can get the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    static Scanner scanner;

    /** Make a scanner available for scanInt */
    static {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /** Read two integers, and print counting from start through end */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int start = scanInt("Enter start number: ");
        int end = scanInt("Enter end number: ");

        int step = start < end ? 1 : -1;

        // Correct end, in order to use inequality test in for-loop
        end += step;

        for (int i = start; i != end; i += step) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%d ", i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /** Generic function guaranteed to return an int */
    static public int scanInt(String prompt) {

        System.out.print(prompt);
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Input must be a whole number. Try again: ");
            scanner.next();
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If Java 8 is applicable here, [`IntStream.rangeClosed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) will be a good candidate for generating the number sequence. However, since it only generates in an *increasing* order, you'll need to [apply some useful arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011264/1144592) to reverse the values:

```
private static String getSequence(int a, int b) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(Math.min(a, b), Math.max(a, b))
                    .map(i -> b < a ? b - i + a : i)
                    .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

The first `map()` uses `b - i + a` for each element of the stream if `b < a`, i.e. for the decreasing order. The second `map()` simply generates the desired space-delimited `String` result.

With the help of [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and a method to handle validation from the `Scanner` instance, the Java 8 implementation can be as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println(getSequence(getInteger(scanner), getInteger(scanner)));
    }
}

private static int getInteger(Scanner scanner) {
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter integers only.");
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.nextInt();
}

private static String getSequence(int a, int b) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(Math.min(a, b), Math.max(a, b))
                    .map(i -> b < a ? b - i + a : i)
                    .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

One thing to note, the use of [`scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) within the `while`-loop is to 'reset' the `Scanner` token parsing, when it encounters an invalid input.